# Windows Server Error Log Filter

Tags: windows-server-2008, website, filtering, logging

How do I filter the Error Log (Windows Server 2008) for errors from one particular website hosted on the server? The site is using a unique Application Pool, and runs under the context of the application pool user, so I could use that instead.

I was told by a client that there was an error, but he can't give me an approximate time, and there's too many other warnings listed to search through them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Search for the client IP in the IIS log, and identify the request by HTTP return code and or URI stem. There you'll have an exact timestamp (by default, UTC+00)

Comment: Sorry, when I say, "I was told by a client", I'm referring to a person, not an application. :) Nobody knows the IP of the site visitor.

Comment: "Nobody knows the IP of the site visitor" - Have the person determine his IP address, just search "What Is My IP Address?" in google

Comment: IP address is not available. Is there any other way? The visitor was my client's customer who told him, and I don't want to make them go through the hassle. Basically, I just want to know if there's a way knowing nothing but IIS info about the site (URL, application pool, etc).